# Match title(string) in a table with form input title(string)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a *issue* table in my database. This *issues* table has a unique constraint on its *issueTitle* column.

Now I want to store another title, if another title with same name doesn't exists.
I used where clause in laravel.
It works for below cases which have title like this:

> Title field in table: 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello'
>   Title from form data :'hello', 'HELLO' ,  ' Hello'

But it doesn't work for these cases:

> Title field in table: 'Hello World', 'Hello World?',
>   Title from form data :'hello(more than one space)World', 'HELLO WORLD'

I hope you got it. I want to check if it's unique title only then store it in the table.

I tried to check the title if it exists with same name. If it exists, redirected to a page with error having 'issue already exists'.

**IssuesController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'    => 'required|max:255',
        'category' => 'required|not_in:0',
        'body'     => 'required',
    ]);

    $issue = new Issue;
    $issue->issue_title = Input::get('title');

    if (Issue::where('issue_title', $issue->issue_title)->first()) {
        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('error', 'Issue already raised!');
    }

    $issue->issue_body = Input::get('body');
    $issue->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $issue->cat_id = 1;
    $issue->save();

    return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Issue raised successfully!');

}
```

I want every title stored unique. 
What I think can be done is :

> Remove all whitespaces
>   Make whole sentence to small letter
>   Remove marks like (?,.,!) from end.
>   Example: 
>   Careless police in Utopia *becomes* carelesspoliceinutopia

Also we can't do this to store in database for first time because it will be hard to retrieve it and show on another view.
I think ***it will better to get the title from database, change it in the above form, do the same with input data and, then compare it.***

Comment: Would the [`Str::slug()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-slug) method be an option?

Comment: @Dan It's perfect. It will work for the coming form input. But now I have to first check for the existing title in the table. How to check if exists or not with this title? As stored title is not in this form.

Comment: Your best option would be to add a new `slug` column to the `issues` table, then iterating through all the issues and save the generated slug.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari How are these stored in table? Are these already inserted via seeder or those are also user inputs?

Comment: @vivek_23 If a user raises an issue it gets stored. I don't want a duplicate issue to be stored by the same user or another user. So i have to check if it already exists before storing in databse.

Comment: @Dan your idea is good, but I have to regenerate a column along with existing titles slugs. That's a problem.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari In that case, you might probably want to give them suggestions retrieved from the database. So, the user could see those and click on the one that suits the best.

Comment: @vivek_23 That's good idea. But that way I can't prevent the user from submitting it.

Comment: You could also recreate the `Str::slug()` function in MySQL and using this along with a custom select.

Comment: I think It will more effective If I implement Dan's and Vivek_23's suggestions. I will try to alter whole table.

Comment: Make a backup before! Good luck!

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari They need to appear while user types the title of the issue. Like how StackOverflow shows suggestions before you post a question. But, all in all, what you are trying to achieve is a little tricky. It's not just about words being the same, it is also but nuances of the typed sentence you need to understand if you want to achieve uniqueness. I am afraid it's more than string comparison.

Comment: @vivek_23 exactly.